# Gremlin Python Gizmo how to query in graph db

Tags: python, graph, gremlin, janusgraph

I've pushed data using gremlin-python. Now I want to run spcific queries on it. I'm using gizmo for that.

I basically want to achieve the degree of centrality for each node. How do I do that?

Currently I've query to return the same as :

```
g.V().group().
......1> by(id).
......2> by(union(__(), outE('mentions').count()).fold())
```

How I'm achieving that is:

```
def query(self, q):
    from gizmo import Mapper, Request
    from gremlinpy import Gremlin

    req = Request('localhost', 8182)
    gremlin = Gremlin('g')

    mapper = Mapper(request=req, gremlin=gremlin)
    # s = mapper.gremlin.V().inE('mentions').count().toList()
    # res = mapper.query(gremlin=s)

    # print(res.get_data()[0])
    print("Something")

    res = mapper.query(script=q)

    # print(res.get_data()[0])
    print("Something")
    print(res.data)

    print(res.first(), res.data)
    # exit(0)
    return res.first()
```

What I want is to display the data fetched inside **res** variable.

But each time I get errors as :

```
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'data'
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'get_data'
```

or anything similar which I try.

How do I fetch the results fetched from coroutine object?

**NOTE**: The sample query I'm passing to function query() is **g.V().count()**

Is there any other better way to run any generic queries from python in gremlin shell and fetch results?

**Graph DB:** JanusGraph

**Backend:** Cassandra

**Indexing Backend:** Elasticsearch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention gizmo which could relate to multiple projects, but I think you mean this one:

https://github.com/emehrkay/gizmo

According to the documentation, this project is meant for TinkerPop 2.x and Rexster. I don't believe it works with TinkerPop 3.x and Gremlin Server which is what JanusGraph is based on. If you need a Python OGM of some sort for TinkerPop 3.x you might consider:

https://github.com/davebshow/goblin

Comment: Thanks, Goblin seems to work in our use case of problem. :-)